# sshpass with sftp not working from crontab?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron, sftp, sshpass

I have a ssh script (for testing purpose) that I can run successfully from cmd:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'password' /usr/bin/sftp user@host:/out/test/ <<< $'put -r /data/test/*'
```

A `./script.sh` runs absolutely fine and uploads all files to remote.

But when I call script.sh from `crontab`, nothing happens. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I could get it working as follows:

```
/usr/bin/lftp sftp://user:pass@host -e "set sftp:auto-confirm yes; 
    set net:timeout 10; set net:max-retries 3; mirror -R --max-errors=1 --verbose=1 
   /local/test /remote/test; quit;"
```

This syncs all files inside `/local/test/` to the remote sftp folder.